# ImageResizing PsdComposer Demo is not working with simple parameter

Tags: image-resizing

I've tried to run the demo for PsdComposer in both 3.3.3 and 4.0.5.  Let's stick to 4.0.5 since that is the latest since I'm probably doing the same wrong thing in both.  The default.aspx I'm running is:

```
\resizer-4-0-5\Samples\PsdComposerSample\Default.aspx?text1=abcd
or
http://localhost:51482/Default.aspx?text1=abc
```

When I debug through default.aspx.cs I see text1 processing and SetText setting the proper data.  However, I get a broken image showing.  If I do not put in the text1=abcd, I get the correct image as I expect.

Here is the URL generated:

```
http://localhost:51482/text.psd?format=png&layerColors=&layerVisibility=dGV4dDI%3d%7c1%7c&layerRedraw=dGV4dDI%3d%7c1%7c&layerText=dGV4dDI%3d%7cYWJj%7c&renderer=psdplugin
```

Comment: In order to get an error message and stack trace, you need to put the offending URL directly into your address bar. A broken image icon simply indicates that the request failed in some manner.

Comment: Given that this only happens with text, it's likely that .NET cannot locate the font used in the PSD, which might be what you see in the error message.